# DOM input .value returns null using getElementById in function

Tags: javascript, dom

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <input id="LinkInput" type="text">
    <button id="Add">Add Link</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    document.getElementById("Add").addEventListener("click", addLink);
});

var addLink = function () {
    let link = document.getElementById("LinkInput").value;
    console.log("link is " + link);
}
```

Paste a link into the input element and then click the button. The following is printed to the console.

```
link is null
```

If I instead `console.log` the return of 'document.getElementById("LinkInput")', this is returned:

```
<input id="LinkInput" type="text">
```

[Browser-Sync version 2.27.7](https://browsersync.io/) is being used to serve the files. The CLI command used was:

```sh
browser-sync start --server --directory --files "*/**"
```

#### Question

Based on [this w3schools js example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_text_value), `.value` should return the value typed into the `<input>` instead of null. Why does it not?

Comment: The `.value` property of an `<input />` element will never return `null`. It will always be the content of the element (or the empty string if there's no content). Your example works as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/0thzwevs/

Comment: you're using two ids. `GametableLinkInput` and `LinkInput`

Comment: @bamtheboozle that was a mistake when transferring and generic-ifying my code when posting the question.

Comment: @Andreas that's curious. I just tested it and it works when I open the HTML doc in Chrome instead of through Browser-Sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem originates with browser-sync, not the code or the browser.

Run

```
npm update browser-sync
```

and then try again.